# pylab cannot be imported while using anaconda

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and anaconda is already installed in my machine. but while I try to import pylab, it gives me following error. any suggestions please?

```
from pylab import *
  File "/home/trina/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/home/trina/Pictures/python/matplotlib.py", line 9, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
ImportError: No module named pylab
```

Comment: Is the name of your script `matplotlib.py` - if so, you better rename it :)

Comment: no, the name is neither pylab.py nor matplotlib.py, I don't know where they getting these script names from

Comment: Can you add the output of `import sys; print sys.path` to your question, please?

Comment: I just figured out I have a script named matplotlib.py in that directory, removed it and now it works fine, thanks for the suggestion anyway :)